# How to create css class in imported css file with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css, file, import

i want to figure out **how to add new class** to css file, when i've got that file **imported** into javascript:

```js
import "./styles.css"

//add class to that file
```

I don't want to insert new file to 'link' tag, only to modify that imported file

Comment: Can you specify why would you want to do that? The approach you suggest is not possible and difficult to justify even if it was

Comment: @MORÈ in vanilla javascript

Comment: @wiktus239 - this was an just exercise on javascript. And i can't find out how i can add something into imported file

Comment: @wiktus239 more precisely, the task was to create a css class and then add it to the element based on its html data- * attribute and the class i've added manually to css file and added that class by javascript. But that first line of javascript file suggests(in my opinion) that i should create that class in javascript > add to css file > then add class to elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the CSS class in styles.css and then using javascript add that class to the HTML element. You can also add new data attributes using javascript as shown in the image below, like this:

```
yourElement.dataset.myDatasetName = 'datasetValue';
```

Read all about how to use data-* attributes here: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/quick-guide-to-using-data-attributes-f1f2c3161d5f

[image: Adding new dataset attribute]